# Three.js Optimize Lots of Objects

Tags: three.js

Here, when I try to load more mesh in the scene the rotate and pan functionalities are getting slow where there is a slow response while I try to rotate/pan/zoom the object. Is there any way to optimize the objects/controls to get a better response while rotate/pan/zoom the object.

Thanks in advance. Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ax65y723/1/

```
var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

    init();
    render(); // remove when using next line for animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
    //animate();

    function init() {


        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 500;

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.addEventListener('change', render); // remove when using animation loop
        // enable animation loop when using damping or autorotation
        //controls.enableDamping = true;
        //controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
        controls.enableZoom = true;

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xcccccc);
        scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0xcccccc, 0.002);


        var container = document.getElementById('container');
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // world

        var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 10, 30, 4, 1);
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, flatShading: true });

        for (var i = 0; i < 75000; i++) {
            var lod = new THREE.LOD();
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            mesh.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
            mesh.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
            mesh.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
            mesh.updateMatrix();
            mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
            lod.addLevel(mesh, i * 75);
            scene.add(lod);
            // scene.add( mesh );

        }
        // lights

        var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
        scene.add(light);

        var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x002288);
        light.position.set(-1, -1, -1);
        scene.add(light);

        var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
        scene.add(light);

    }

    function onWindowResize() {

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    }

    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        controls.update(); // required if controls.enableDamping = true, or if controls.autoRotate = true

        render();

    }

    function render() {

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of draw calls kills the performance of your demo. Instead of creating a mesh for each cylinder, you can use instanced rendering by using [THREE.InstancedMesh](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh). In this way, you render all cylinders with one draw call and can still modify their individual transformation.

```js
  var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

  init();
  render();

  function init() {


    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 500;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.addEventListener('change', render); // remove when using animation loop
    // enable animation loop when using damping or autorotation
    //controls.enableDamping = true;
    //controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
    controls.enableZoom = true;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xcccccc);
    scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0xcccccc, 0.002);


    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // world

    var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0, 10, 30, 4, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, flatShading: true });

    var mesh = new THREE.InstancedMesh( geometry, material, 75000 );
    scene.add( mesh );

    var dummy = new THREE.Object3D();

    for (var i = 0; i < 75000; i++) {

      dummy.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
      dummy.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000;
      dummy.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1000

      dummy.updateMatrix();

      mesh.setMatrixAt( i ++, dummy.matrix );

    }
    // lights

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
    scene.add(light);

    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x002288);
    light.position.set(-1, -1, -1);
    scene.add(light);

    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222);
    scene.add(light);

  }

  function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  }

  function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    controls.update(); // required if controls.enableDamping = true, or if controls.autoRotate = true

    render();

  }

  function render() {

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

  }
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```